# ASP VBScript code gives "800a0005 Runtime error Invalid Procedure Call"

Tags: asp-classic, vbscript, nstextattachment

The ASP code getting the below error while writing text to file.

Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a0005'

Invalid Procedure call or argument

The Line in which i get the above error is below,

```
oFile.Write Chr(AscB(MidB(FileData,nIndex,1)))
```

The issue is caused when I am uploading a file. I will face this error only in Development environment. But the same code is working good in the Production environment. I could not understand why the error causes in Dev environment only.

Comment: You probably don't choose any file to upload.

Answer (score 0):

You have a method with three nested function calls. Try breaking that up to see which call actually causes the error:

```
b = MidB(FileData, nIndex, 1)
i = AscB(b)
c = Chr(i)
oFile.Write c
```